# Strange situation: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pic_name' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I have a problem in python. I have no idea why it happen.
It should be finish in "print ('done')" line.

Following is my sample python code.

```
def check_count(img, count):

    global index_image_processing
    detection_count = count
    print ('index= ', index_image_processing)
    print ('detection_count = ', detection_count)

    if detection_count == 0:
        index_image_processing += 1 
        print ('1-index= ', index_image_processing)
        if index_image_processing <= 6:
            pic_plate_detect(img)
        else:
            print ('Cannot find')
            pic_name = 'Fail' + '.jpg'
        print ('2-index= ', index_image_processing)
        print ('detection_count=', detection_count)

    elif detection_count == 1:
        pic_name = 'single' + '.jpg'
        print ('detection_count == 1')
    elif detection_count >= 2:
        pic_name = 'muti_result' + '.jpg'
        print ('detection_count >= 2')

    print pic_name
    pic_path = './' + pic_name
    cv2.imwrite(pic_path, img)

    print ('done')
```

And, my result is below:

```
('index= ', 1)
('detection_count=', 1)
detection_count == 1
single.jpg
done
('2-index= ', 1)
('detection_count=', 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pic_name' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: you are just initialising the variable inside the elif parts but you are trying to access its outside that is the problem . So you can do one thing is just initialise it first with simple ' '  value. Those variables when you just try to want to use outside the scope has to be initialise first. you can define a sample or empty data.

Comment: If `detection_count` is 0 and `index_image_processing` <= 6 you will never initialize `pic_name`.

Comment: @VikasPeriyadath It's fine to initialize a Python variable within an if block and use it outside of the block.  You must however initialize it in all possible branches.

Comment: @PaulCornelius yeah I just want to point out that only. But only for easy unserstanding I have given description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pic_name is never created when detection_count is 0 and index_image_processing <=6, yet you try to print it unconditionally.
Initialize it like so:

```
pic_name = None
```

Then  run your logic and print only if it's not `None`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `pic_name` by performing a concatenation on it (i.e. `pic_name = 'single' + '.jpg'`) without having it initialized it first. This is disallowed in python, in contrast to value *assignment* (i.e. `pic_name = 'single'`).